# Access JSON item with variable key name

Tags: c#, json, mediawiki, wikidata, wikidata-api

The following is my JSON data which happens to be the format supplied by Wikidata, although greatly trimmed down for clarity.

```
{
"entities": {
    "Q200405": {
        "id": "Q200405",
        "type": "item",
        "claims": "Cheese"
        }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to access this data within c#. My problem is that the Q200405 is dynamic - it is basically the record number that I am retrieving. For example, another page might give me

```
{
"entities": {
    "Q123456": {
        "id": "Q123456",
        "type": "item",
        "claims": "Lemon"
        }
    }
}
```

My best attempt so far was using Json.NET (Newtonsoft)
;

```
json = "{\"entities\":{\"Q200405\" {\"id\":\"Q200405\",\"type\":\"item\",\"claims\":\"Cheese\"}}}";

var Query = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
string entities = Query.entities.ToString();

Query = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(entities);
string entity = Query.Q200405.ToString();

Query = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(entity);
string id = Query.id.ToString();
string claims = Query.claims.ToString();
```

This works, but obviously hardcoding *Query.Q200405.ToString()* is not the ideal solution! I probably should not be doing multiple Deserialize statements to drill down into the data either?

My question is what is the best way to read the above JSON format into a c# program?

Comment: Seems like you might want some sort of X-path query for json. Is it fair to assume you don't have the id value when you need it? Or is it a parameter in this case?

Comment: Once you get the json into .NET I highly recommend you take a look at restsharp: http://restsharp.org/ as far as best practices go.

Comment: I do not know the ID. The original sample was a lookup of John Hurt on wikidata.org  The ID just happens to be their record number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well if you want to put the names into string variables, just use `JObject`:

```
string id = "Q200405"; // Or wherever you get that from
string text = "{\"entities...";
var json = JObject.Parse(text);

var claim = json["entities"][id];

string claims = (string) claim["claims"];
string type = (string) claim["type"];
// etc
```

Basically LINQ to JSON is really what you want here.

EDIT: If you don't know the ID beforehand, you can use:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(text);
var entities = (JObject) json["entities"];
var entity = entities.Properties().First();
var id = entity.Name;
var claim = (JObject) entity.Value;
string claims = (string) claim["claims"];
string type = (string) claim["type"];
Console.WriteLine(new { claims, type, id });
```

Comment: That method works but I do not know the id and it varies between records. However, in my case I could simply use  string id = text.Substring(14,7); although that does seem a poor way to do things!

Comment: @MortimerCat: No, if you don't know the ID but it's the only ID, you can use `json["entities"].First` - that will get the first child token.

Comment: Yep, thats great. I had missed those First and FirstOrDefault methods. Thanks.

Comment: Now that I actually try your latest version I get the error message _Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty_ on the `string claims = (string) claim["claims"];` line

Comment: @MortimerCat: Okay, will have a look now.

Comment: @MortimerCat: Fixed now - give that a try. (It works for me with your sample JSON)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that. I have my program working now :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can parse it

```
class Data
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string claims { get; set; }
}

var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,Data>>>(json);
Data data = obj["entities"].FirstOrDefault().Value;
```